# Given k sets of integers find the minimum difference between k elements chosen

Tags: c

I have an algorithmic problem.Given k sets of integers>0(which are not the same size necessarily) ,I must pick k numbers one from each set so that the difference between the maximum value and the minimum value is minimum.
Example:
k=5

set 1:89 45 22 16

set 2:89 34

set 3:37 62 89

set 4:89 96

set 5:89 91 94

Answer: pick 89 from all sets difference 0.

Example 2(more difficult)
k=5

set 1:12 19 44 52 59 100

set 2:35 60 90 94 98 101

set 3:48 49 57 64 78 90

set 4:15 38 56 90 97

set 5:54 58 59 89 202

Answer: k elements picked:52,60,57,56,54) difference 60-52=8.

Any suggestions on how to approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

- Construct `setUnion` with a union of all sets
- Initialize `currentBest` difference to the distance between the largest and the smallest elements of the union
- For each element of `setUnion`, go through the original `K` sets, and find the closest element that is greater than or equal to it. You will have a set of up to `K` numbers. Find their `min` and `max`, and check it against the `currentBest` difference
- Upon completion `currentBest` will have the answer to your problem.

If the size of the union is `N` and you use an ordered representation for your `K` sets, this algorithm finds the answer in `O(N*K*LogN)` time.

Comment: For example 2 I make the setunion {12,15,19,35,....202}. I take the current best difference 202-12=190 and then I run the algorithm for value 12 find nearest k-1 elements,find difference compare with previous difference,then run again for 15.....then again for 202?Have i understood correct?Thanks for the quick response.